# Unsatisfied dependency for Repository into Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to implement JUnit 5 test in order to test services:

***JPA Repository:***

```
@Repository
public interface RiskFilterRepository extends JpaRepository<RiskFilters, Integer> {
    .....
}
```

***Service Interface:***

```
public interface RiskFilterService {
    ......
}
```

***Service implementation:***

```
@Service
@Qualifier("riskFilterService")
@Transactional
public class RiskFilterServiceImpl implements RiskFilterService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterRepository dao;
    ...
}
```

***Service for testing:***

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        ......
    }
}
```

***JUnit test***

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.datalis.plugin.service.RiskFilterRepository"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = { RiskFilterServiceImpl.class, RiskFilterService.class } )
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { H2TestProfileJPAConfig.class })
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"org.entity"})
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "entityManager")
    EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterRepository repository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
       ....
    }    
}
```

When I run the code I get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'riskFilterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.datalis.plugin.service.RiskFilterRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

Full error stack: https://pastebin.com/84D0v6EQ

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

EDIT: I tried this:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    @Transactional
    public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value = "entityManager")
        EntityManager manager;

        @Autowired
        private RiskFilterRepository repository;

        @BeforeEach
        public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        }

        @Test
        public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
           ....
        }    
    }
```

I get this error when I run the JUnit code:

```
 Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [org.datalis.rest.api.server.filter.bincountrycheck.BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest]: BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
```

Comment: can you add `RiskFilterRepository ` to ContextConfiguration ?

Comment: I tried this but this is a Interface not a class? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Remove `@ContextConfiguration`, `@EntityScan`, `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Only add `@SpringBootTest` (don't pass the configuration). It will use the application class to bootstrap your test context. You are trying to outsmart Spring Boot. If you just want a unit test, strip all the spring stuff from the test, create a service instance yourself, mock the dependencies and write the test.

Comment: See the updated post. I get error for missing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing BinCountryCheckFilterImpl then you need to @Autowire RiskFilterService since it's a dependency of the BinCountryCheckFilterImpl. Is your intention to have this be an integration test or a unit test?